# NavigationSplitView in swiftUI: change NavigationSplitViewVisibility after selection

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios16

I have a side bar implemented via `NavigationSplitView`.
Once the app is launched for the first time I have the setting

```
NavigationSplitViewVisibility.detailOnly
```

Main content of the app is in the `VStack` within `detail` part of the `NavigationSplitView`.

The user then clicks on the side-bar toggle button and select the item in the menu.

The `detail` part is then updated.

However, the sidebar stays open.

Is there a way to change back to

```
NavigationSplitViewVisibility.detailOnly
```

after the user selected an item?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showDetailsOnly = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.detailOnly
    

    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $showDetailsOnly) {
                ...list of items...
            }
            detail: {
                VStack {
                       ...main content, depending on the selected item...
                    
                }
            }
                
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
   List(selection: $selection) {
       //List content
   }
} detail: {
   //Detal view
}
.onChange(of: selection) {_ in
   columnVisibility = .detailOnly
}
```